# Creating Regex pattern from user input doesn't work when it contains backslash

Tags: java, regex, irc

I have tried to create a way to add banned words to my IRC moderating bot via IRC message.
The add syntax is the following:

```
!addword #channel+regex+5+enabled
```

where 'regex' is a regular expression which will be used to check for banned words in the sent message.

My problem is that word boundaries '\b' don't work. So, if I try to do

```
!addword #channel+\bban\b+5+enabled
```

the bot doesn't ban the word 'ban', only when the sent message content equals 'ban'. So for example the line 'ban me please' won't get banned. Using double backslash doesn't work at all.

Other regex things (like [abc], ., etc) work, so I must assume this has something to do with the character '\'.

The code that handles it is the following:

adding the banned word:

```
word = s.substring(nthOccurrence(s, '+', 1) + 1,
                nthOccurrence(s, '+', 2));
```

where 's' is the message that adds the banned word

pattern matching:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(word.toLowerCase());
Matcher m=p.matcher(sentMessage.toLowerCase());
if(m.matches()) sendBAN(targetChannel, sender);
```

The answer might be blatantly obvious, but I just cannot figure it out. Thank you to anyone who can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to escape the word boundaries in java so it will become `\\bban\\b` and use `find()` instead of `matches()`

Example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String[] test = {"ban me please","ban","This should not be banned","hello"};
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bban\\b");
    for(String  s: test) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Banning: " + s);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Banning: " + s);
        }
    }   
}
```

Provides the following:

```
Banning: ban me please
Banning: ban
Not Banning: This should not be banned
Not Banning: hello
```

Comment: Then send the correct parameter. `!addword #channel+\\bban\\b+5+enabled`. I was just providing an example.